# Widget width not updating after value change

Tags: flutter, dart, state-management

I am trying to build a side menu that will open and close when the arrow icon at the bottom of the vertical app bar seen in the screenshots below is pressed. I am currently doing this by using a global bool value named isleftWidgetCollapsed which will change the width of the side menu to 0 if isleftWidgetCollapsed is set to true.

It seems to be working correctly but only when I resize the app window as seen in the screenshots below. How can I get it to work on the press of the IconButton and without having to resize the app window every time?

[image]
[image]

Section of code from buildLeftMenu.dart:

```
Widget buildLeft(context, HomeViewModel model) {
  final _scrollbar = ScrollController();
  return Material(
    textStyle: TextStyle(
      color: Colors.white70,
      fontFamily: 'Lato',
    ),
    child: Row(
      children: [
        Container(
          width: (gb.isleftWidgetCollapsed==true)
              ? 0
              : MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * .20, //21.width,
          height: 100.height,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: MainTheme.primary[50], //Colors.blueAccent[400],
          ),
```

Section of code from the mainHomeView.dart:

```
          body: Container(
            child: Row(
              children: [
                VerticalAppBar(),
                buildLeft(context, HomeViewModel()),
        ...
```

onPressed section from VerticalAppBar.dart:

```
        leading: RotatedBox(
            quarterTurns: 1,
            child: IconButton(
              icon: Icon(gb.isleftWidgetCollapsed
                  ? Icons.arrow_right
                  : Icons.arrow_left),
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {  
                  gb.isleftWidgetCollapsed = !gb.isleftWidgetCollapsed;
                  buildLeft(context, HomeViewModel());
                });
              },
            )),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

globals.dart :

```
library my_prj.globals;

bool isLoggedIn = false;

bool isleftWidgetCollapsed = false;
```

Comment: I suggest you to use state management library like ```Provider```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The call to `buildLeft` inside `onPressed` is doing nothing:

```
onPressed: () {
  setState(() {  
    gb.isleftWidgetCollapsed = !gb.isleftWidgetCollapsed;
    buildLeft(context, HomeViewModel());
  });
},
```

Here is a solution using [hooks_riverpod](https://pub.dev/packages/hooks_riverpod) package. You will find all the info about this package here: http://riverpod.dev/

[image]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_hooks/flutter_hooks.dart';
import 'package:hooks_riverpod/hooks_riverpod.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    ProviderScope(
      child: MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        title: 'Flutter Demo',
        home: HomePage(),
      ),
    ),
  );
}

class HomePage extends HookWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final menuOpened = useProvider(menuOpenedProvider).state;
    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          AnimatedPositioned(
            duration: Duration(milliseconds: 300),
            top: 0,
            right: 0,
            bottom: 0,
            left: menuOpened
                ? kVerticalBarWidth + kLeftMenuWidth
                : kVerticalBarWidth,
            child: Content(),
          ),
          AnimatedPositioned(
            duration: Duration(milliseconds: 300),
            top: 0,
            bottom: 0,
            left: menuOpened
                ? kVerticalBarWidth
                : kVerticalBarWidth - kLeftMenuWidth,
            child: LeftMenu(),
          ),
          Align(alignment: Alignment.centerLeft, child: VerticalAppBar()),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class VerticalAppBar extends HookWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final menuOpened = useProvider(menuOpenedProvider).state;
    return Container(
      width: kVerticalBarWidth,
      color: kVerticalBarColor,
      child: Align(
        alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
        child: IconButton(
            onPressed: () =>
                context.read(menuOpenedProvider).state = !menuOpened,
            icon: Icon(menuOpened ? Icons.arrow_left : Icons.arrow_right)),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class LeftMenu extends HookWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: kLeftMenuColor,
      width: 200.0,
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          ...List.generate(20, (index) => Text('Menu Item $index')),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Content extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: kContentColor,
      child: Center(
        child: Text('CONTENT'),
      ),
    );
  }
}

// Provider for the Menu State
final menuOpenedProvider = StateProvider((ref) => true);

// Some constants
const double kVerticalBarWidth = 48.0;
const double kLeftMenuWidth = 200.0;
const Color kVerticalBarColor = Color(0xffc19277);
const Color kLeftMenuColor = Color(0xffe1bc91);
const Color kContentColor = Color(0xff62959c);
```

Comment: If you provide more info about how you manage the state of `gb`, we will be able to help you with more details.

Comment: Well buildLeft is a widget I think right? And you're right sorry I should have probably included that but gb is just an alias for a global library where I have the value of isleftWidgetCollapsed stored which I import using ``` import 'package:epic_games_ui/globals.dart' as gb;```

Comment: Nope, `buildLeft` is a method returning a `Widget`: `Widget buildLeft(context, HomeViewModel model) {...}`. This is why your menu is opened/closed when you resize the windows, because this triggers a rebuild of the application.

Comment: Knowing how you import `gb` still doesn't tell me much about what's inside.

Comment: Just updated the post with the contents of globals.dart.  How could I go about creating a widget that listens for the value of isleftWidgetCollapsed as you suggested ?

Comment: There are many ways. Do you already use packages for State Management?

Comment: Nope, I’m looking into Provider but am not sure how I would go about it.

Comment: Ok, I will update my answer with Riverpod. I would recommend Riverpod over Provider. Both are from the same author, Remi ROUSSELET. Riverpod is easier, with less boilerplate.